# Explanation on the current circulation in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

I'm studying the electromagnetsim, and I couldn't find a complete explanation on how the current flows in a circuit; I mean, basically, how do I decide whether the current is flowing in or out a node? I'm interested in RC and RLC circuits only.
I would be grateful if anyone could provide me a link or somewhat else that could be useful; thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know Kirchhoff's current law? Current can't flow overall in or out of a node. All currents in must be balanced by currents out.

Answer (score 0):

[This maybe of some help.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229619/nodal-analysis-how-to-determine-high-and-low-potential-for-current)
I feel the question is missing something, if you could provide more clarity as to what you are looking for, I can give you some insight.